# Which one to use — "support" or "sports"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, verbs

I have read about many times like as given below:

> Nokia N8 Mobile **Support** A 12-Megapixel Camera.

and

> Nokia N8 Mobile **Sports** A 12-Megapixel Camera.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any difference in the meaning of those two words here?
2. If yes, then when should one use *support* and when *sports*?

Comment: Related: [What does ‘Sport’ mean when you say ‘the new Apple iPad sports cameras for video conferencing’?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11984/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one should read *supports*, not *support*. Also, *support* doesn't really make sense in the context you gave: when talking about devices, to *support* means to *have the ability to use* something with the device, but to *sport* means simply to *have* a feature.

For example, my netbook *sports* (has) USB connectors, therefore it *supports* USB devices.

Comment: Yep - this usage of *sports* comes from the meaning of the verb *to sport* which means [to wear or be decorated with](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sport_3).

Comment: It means in my case `Sport` word is correct. Am i right?

Comment: @Vikas: Yes, that's right: *The Nokia N8 mobile sports a 12-megapixel camera.*

Answer (score 6):

The word that works here is "sports" and it means the same as "features" would in

> Nokia n8 Mobile *features* a 12-megapixel camera.

It might also *support* such a camera, but that is not the intent of the copywriter or reviewer in such a case.